# Two Queries in PHP Assoc Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How can I create an associative array in PHP using two different queries in a while statement?

One query has to already be in the while statement, here's the code without using arrays, I want to convert this to be like

"Category" => Number of posts in that Category

**Current Code:**

```
<?php while ($gC = mysqli_fetch_object($GetBlog->CategoryQuery)){
         $GetCategoryNum = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM BlogPosts WHERE BlogID='$GetBlog->ID' AND CategoryID='$gC->ID'"));?>
         <h6 class="blog-cats"> 
         <?php echo $gC->Name . " "; ?> (<a href="/Blogs/?ID=<?php echo $GBID;?>&CatID=<?php echo $gC->ID;?>"><?php echo $GetCategoryNum;?></a>)
         </h6><br>
      <? } ?>
```

For reference to *$GetBlog->CategoryQuery*, here's the query:

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM BlogCategories");
```

Sorry if this makes no sense, there are two different tables, the categories table and the posts table, the posts table records the category of the post in each row which is why I need a while loop to determine the number of posts in that category associated to a specific blog.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy, just define `array` just before `while` loop and append values in array using array key value pairs,

Like this:

```
<?php 
         $carArray=array();
         while ($gC = mysqli_fetch_object($GetBlog->CategoryQuery)){
         $GetCategoryNum = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM BlogPosts WHERE BlogID='$GetBlog->ID' AND CategoryID='$gC->ID'"));?>
         <h6 class="blog-cats"> 
         <?php 
           $carArray[$gC->ID]=$GetCategoryNum; 
          // Adding values in array where $gC->ID(Category ID) is the key and $GetCategoryNum is value. 
         ?>
         <?php echo $gC->Name . " "; ?> (<a href="/Blogs/?ID=<?php echo $GBID;?>&CatID=<?php echo $gC->ID;?>"><?php echo $GetCategoryNum;?></a>)
         </h6><br>
      <? } ?>

<?php print_r($carArray); // Just for checking final result.  ?>
```